# Table positioning not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

So I am creating a table that is supposed to be all the way to the left of its area. For some reason whatever I do, `margin, padding` etc will not move the table. Is it something in my jquery code or in my css that I have overlooked that is keeping the table to the right? Or is just a limitation of using tables.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bAZhJ/)

Comment: Quickfix would be to add position:absolute; on your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking what @shriek said just add `position: absolute` to your table.